# Power BI, Postgres, and materialized views

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, materialized-views

I've created a materialized view in Postgres. I can see the new table and the data using DBeaver. It resides in the same schema as my other tables.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the mv to appear in Power BI. When I create a new source it only shows me tables.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

In Power Query, I have performed a Refresh All and I've tried to reconfigure the Navigation step. No success.

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge this is not supported. As a work around, you can create a view on top of this materialized view. This should work, since views are supported.

Comment: thanks. the more I dig into it, I'm coming to that realization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Native SQL Query in the [Postgres Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/postgresql), eg `select * from Labors_mv`.